# Aligning widgets using grid between multiple Tkinter LabelFrames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a Tkinter layout that has labels and entry fields vertically aligned across multiple `LabelFrame` boxes.

Here's some simplified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

win = Frame()
win.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame_a = LabelFrame(win, text='Top frame', padx=5, pady=5)
frame_b = LabelFrame(win, text='Bottom frame', padx=5, pady=5)
frame_a.grid(sticky=E+W)
frame_b.grid(sticky=E+W)

for frame in frame_a, frame_b:
    for col in 0, 1, 2:
        frame.columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

Label(win, text='Hi').grid(in_=frame_a, sticky=W)
Label(win, text='Longer label, shorter box').grid(in_=frame_b, sticky=W)

Entry(win).grid(in_=frame_a, row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
Entry(win, width=5).grid(in_=frame_b, row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

win.mainloop()
```

The above code produces a window that looks like the below:

[image: Incorrect image produced by above code]

Whereas I'm looking to find some way of aligning the fields so the window looks more like this (with thanks to MS Paint):

[image: Desired image]

I've played around with `in_` arguments to `grid()`, but not achieved very much, and I can't think of anything else to experiment with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't do what you want. `grid` does not manage its rows and columns across multiple containers.

However, there are at least a couple ways to achieve the effect you are wanting. One way is to give the first column in each container an explicit, identical width. To do that you can use the `grid_columnconfigure` method to give each column a minimum width.

Another solution is to give each label an identical width, which effectively will set the width of the first column to be the same (assuming all columns in each container have the same weight).

Comment: Is there some way to work out what the maximum width of all of a given set of labels is? I'd prefer to write code that doesn't require hard-coding specific widths where I don't need to, so if possible I'd like to have the code calculate the correct width to use.

Comment: @me_and: well, you know (or can trivially compute) the width of your labels, right? Just set all labels to a width equal to the widest label. Or, you can use the font commands to figure out in pixels exactly how wide a string will be and use that. You can also use `winfo_width` on a widget to get its width, though that will often report 1x1 until the widget is actually displayed on the screen. If you want a proper answer to that question, ask it as a separate question -- comments aren't the right place to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to do what you want, is to change the make the Label text                                  variables, and then, check the len(txt1) against len(txt2), and, set the width variable of both to the longest one. The following code is close. My knowledge is too limited to figure out where the extra space is coming from.

```
    txt1 = StringVar()
    txt2 = StringVar()
    lblWidth = IntVar()
    txt1 = "Hi"
    txt2 = "Longer label, shorter box"

    if (len(txt1) > len(txt2)):
        lblWidth = len(txt1)
    else:
        lblWidth = len(txt2)

    Label(win, text=txt1, width=lblWidth, anchor=W).grid(in_=frame_a)
    Label(win, text=txt2, width=lblWidth, anchor=W).grid(in_=frame_b, sticky=W)
```

Comment: I didn't run your code, but I think It doesn't work unless you use a Mono font. I mean, OOOOO has the same length than IIIII, but the second will be much smaller (in most fonts). Also, in you example, you are setting width=25. Note that 25 characters != 25 pixels ;)