# Aligning Tkinter Grids on Separate Frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do something similar to the user here was doing: [Aligning widgets using grid between multiple Tkinter LabelFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759496/aligning-widgets-using-grid-between-multiple-tkinter-labelframes)

I want to align the label widgets highlighted in red and blue with the grid of text widgets in the frame below it. Even if I specify the width of each widget as the same number of characters and use the same tkFont for both labels and text boxes, I cannot make them have the same width in pixels as you can see. I have heard you can use grid_columnconfigure to do this, but I don't see how as the only parameters are *minsize*, *pad*, and *weight*. I have also tried using pack_propagate but am at a loss to get it to do anything. Is there any way to either align the columns of grids in different frames or specify the exact width in pixels of a label widget?

[image]

The way I previously had my code was where the labels were part of the same grid in the same frame as the text boxes, which avoids the problem but makes it so that the labels are not visible when you scroll down. I want the labels to be visible regardless of which section of the grid you are looking at, but I want them to still line up with the gird for readability.

```
class Window(Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.currRow = -1
    self.currCol = -1
    self.width = 1100
    self.height = 200

    self.topWin = Frame(root)
    self.topWin.pack(side=TOP)

    self.baseWin = Frame(root)
    self.baseWin.pack()

    self.headerWin = Frame(self.baseWin)
    self.headerWin.pack(side=TOP)

    self.leftWin = Frame(self.baseWin)
    self.leftWin.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.leftWin, width=1050, height=200)
    self.bottomWin = Frame(self.canvas)

    self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window(self.width/2, 50, window=self.bottomWin)

    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.baseWin, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.bottomWin.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)


    self.font = tkFont.Font(root=self.bottomWin, family="Helvetica", size=10,
        weight="bold")
    self.headerFont = tkFont.Font(root=self.bottomWin, family="Helvetica",
        size=10, weight="bold")

    self.displayMode = "all"
    self.filterEstimates = False
    self.filterBids = False
    self.filterContact = False
    self.filterRenewal = False

    self.init_window()
    self.loadJobs()

def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

def printColumnHeaders(self):
    j = 0 
    bg = "blue"
    for header in self.headers:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            bg = "blue"
        else:
            bg = "red"
        label = Label(self.headerWin, text=header, font=self.headerFont, width=12, anchor="w", bg=bg)
        label.grid(row=0, column=j, sticky="WE")
        if j == 0:
            label.grid_columnconfigure(j, minsize=50)
        j = j + 1
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this in Tkinter.  Wild idea: have everything in a single grid, with a *fixed* number of lines.  The scrollbar doesn't actually scroll anything: you respond to its `command=` calls yourself by redisplaying a subset of the actual data in the rows of the grid (other than the first row, which contains the headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this before by [making a multicolumn listbox](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/49fa18828cddca44a2befae84cfd67ad). Copy that code and run it; the second example is exactly what you want.